# Группировка Pandas и построение графика

Tags: python, pandas

В результате конкатенации нескольких датафреймов по дате и прилету-вылету получилась таблица
ar_dp_concat вида:

| Date | Status | hours | Flights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.16 | Arriv | 00 | 25 |
| 02.16 | Arriv | 01 | 98 |
| 02.16 | Arriv | 02 | 45 |
| 02.16 | Depart | 01 | 26 |
| 02.16 | Depart | 02 | 99 |
| 02.17 | Arriv | 00 | 100 |
| 02.17 | Arriv | 04 | 101 |
| 02.17 | Depart | 01 | 55 |
| 02.17 | Depart | 03 | 30 |
| 02.17 | Depart | 04 | 99 |

По этой таблице надо построить диаграмму прилета-вылета по датам и часам

Мой код:

```
ar_dp_concat_grouped = ar_dp_concat.groupby([ 'Date','Status', 'hours']).agg({'Flights':'count'}).sort_values(by=[ 'Date', 'Status','hours'], ascending=[True, True, True])
ar_dp_concat_grouped.plot(kind='bar',
                          xlabel='Time',
                          ylabel='Quantity')

for i, val in enumerate(ar_dp_concat_grouped.values):
    plt.text(i, val, int(val), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom', fontdict={'size':8})`
```

дает четыре разных графика на одной оси. И вообще, я сомневаюсь в верности своей группировки.

Сначала я работала с 2-мя разными таблицами - Arriv и Depart, но тогда графики вообще получаются на разных осях.

А мне надо наложение Arriv на Depart по датам и часам в одних осях, разным цветом.

Это возможно? и как это сделать?

Комментарий: вопрос

Большое спасибо, второй вариант как раз то, что мне нужно!
… но на моей таблице почему-то не работает…

```
Date    Status  hours   Flights

0   02.16.2024  Arrival 00  AA 1704

1   02.16.2024  Arrival 00  NK 1166

2   02.16.2024  Arrival 01  NK 3801

3   02.16.2024  Arrival 04  AA 2841

4   02.16.2024  Arrival 05  AA 2821

... ... ... ... ...

1397    02.17.2024  Departure   22  AA 5823

1398    02.17.2024  Departure   22  NK 980

1399    02.17.2024  Departure   22  AA 5281

1400    02.17.2024  Departure   22  AA 1644

1401    02.17.2024  Departure   23  AA 494

2802 rows × 4 columns
```

С датами на самом деле все в порядке, а вот с индексом не понятно - если я применяю ваш код к моим данным

```
    ar_dp_concat[['Date','Status', 'Flights']].pivot_table(columns='Status',index='Date', values='Flights').plot(kind='bar',color=['b','r'])
    plt.show()
```

TypeError: no numeric data to plot

В чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: вам нужно что-то такое https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharex.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharex

Comment: тут смотрите все функции. там есть еще (но не нашёл), когда для всех ax принимается единая шкала значений. и после этого графики синхронизируются по одним и тем же значениям x,  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html

Comment: ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax) - это надо сделать для каждого графика, где xmin-xmax некая единая шкала значений, например. одного из графиков. тогда шкалы всех графиков будут синхронизированы относительно одной шкалы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал под новые данные, где в `Flights` - номера рейсов. Агрегирующая функция в pivot_table - количество.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ar_dp_concat = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['02.16.2024', '02.16.2024', '02.16.2024', '02.16.2024', '02.16.2024', '02.17.2024', '02.17.2024', '02.17.2024', '02.17.2024', '02.17.2024'],
                             'Status': ['Arrival', 'Arrival', 'Arrival', 'Arrival', 'Arrival', 'Departure', 'Departure', 'Departure', 'Departure', 'Departure'],
                             'hours': [0, 0, 1, 4, 5, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23],
                             'Flights': ['AA 1704', 'NK 1166', 'NK 3801', 'AA 2841', 'AA 2821', 'AA 5823', 'NK 980', 'AA 5281', 'AA 1644', 'AA 494']},
                            index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1397, 1398, 1399, 1400, 1401])
ar_dp_concat.Date = pd.to_datetime(ar_dp_concat.Date.add(' ').add(ar_dp_concat.hours.astype(str)), format='%m.%d.%Y %H')
ar_dp_concat[['Date', 'Status', 'Flights']].pivot_table(columns='Status', index='Date', values='Flights', aggfunc='count').plot(kind='bar', color=['b', 'r'])
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, второй вариант как раз то, что мне нужно!
… но на моей таблице почему-то не работает…


Date Status hours Flights
0 02.16.2024 Arrival 00 AA 1704, BA 1933, QF 4648
1 02.16.2024 Arrival 00 NK 1166

ar_dp_concat[['Date','Status', Flights']].pivot_table(columns='Status',index='Date', values='Flights').plot(kind='bar',color=['b','r'])
plt.show()


TypeError: no numeric data to plot

В чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка - размещать в комментариях код и данные - получается каша и ничего не понятно. Код и данные нужно размещать в вопросе (его можно править).

Comment: Прошу прощения, не разобралась... я дополнила вопрос Комментарием внизу

Comment: @NikaTriquetra в первом примере данных у вас `Flights` - числа. Во втором примере данных `Flights` - текст. Поэтому и ошибка. У вас `Flights` чем должно быть?

Comment: вообще-то текст... это обычные авиарейсы, их нужно посчитать за каждый час и отобразить как столбик диаграммы

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо!!!